# If user inputs "sum(x,y)" how can I get x and y as doubles

Tags: c, linux, string, input, terminal

I am writing a simple calculator program such that the user is entered into the programs own console environment. Each new line starts with a $. User will enter commands such as '''sum(x,y)''' '''mul(x,y)''' etc. and the program will take x and y as doubles and execute a function i.e. '''double mul(x, y){return x*y)''' and display the returned value.

I have gotten it to correctly identify the command based on matching the first three characters in the string.

I cant seem to read the numerical values correctly no matter what I do. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

The Code below is from main()

```
    printf("%s", " $    ");
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    sscanf(input,"(%d,%d)",&arg1,&arg2);

    if(strstr(input,"sum")){
        //char *starting_pos = strchr(input,dlm);
        //int position = (starting_pos == NULL ? -1 : (uintptr_t)starting_pos);

        //arg1 = input[position + 1];
        //arg2 = input[position + 3];
        printf("DEBUG: arg1 is %d arg2 is %d\n", arg1,arg2);
        double output = sum(arg1,arg2);
        printf("DEBUG: Output should be: %d\n", output);
        printf("%d\n",output);

    }else if ...
```

The commented section is the remnants of another way I was trying. If anyone can tell me what the right way to do this is I would be very grateful.

Comment: `arg1` and `arg2` should have been declared `double`, and `%lf` should have been used in `sscanf`, instead of `%d`. The return value of `sscanf` also should have been checked.

Comment: If you want `double` values, then why does `sscanf(input,"(%d,%d)",&arg1,&arg2);` parse `arg1` and `arg2` as `int`? Why not `char op[32]; ... if (sscanf(input,"%31[^(](%lf,%lf)", op, &arg1, &arg2) == 3) { /* valid op and args */ }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good job in reading with `fgets()` and then parsing values with `sscanf()`. If I understand the question, and you may have multiple operators followed by two doubles in parenthesis, e.g. `SUM(1.1, 2.2)`, and you want to separate and save the operator, and the double values, then you can use a format string such as:

```
#define MAXOP   32
...
    char op[MAXOP];
    ...
    sscanf (input, "%31[^( ] (%lf,%lf)", op, &x, &y)
```

This will read from `input` separating everything up to a whitespace or `'('` into `op` and then reading the double values into `x` and `y`. By reading the `op` to a whitespace or `'('`, you allow input of `sum(1.1, 2.2)` or `sum (1.1, 2.2)` seamlessly.

For example, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC  1024
#define MAXOP   32

int main (void) {
    
    while (1) {
        char input[MAXC], op[MAXOP];
        double x, y;
        
        fputs ("\nenter OP(x, y): ", stdout);
        fflush (stdout);
        
        if (!fgets (input, MAXC, stdin)) {
            puts ("(user canceled input)");
            return 0;
        }
        if (*input == '\n')
            break;
        
        if (sscanf (input, "%31[^( ] (%lf,%lf)", op, &x, &y) == 3)
            printf (" op: '%s'  x: %.2f  y: %.2f\n", op, x, y);
        else
            fputs ("  error: invalid input.\n", stderr);
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
./bin/sumxy

enter OP(x, y): mult(10.1,12.4)
 op: 'mult'  x: 10.10  y: 12.40

enter OP(x, y): mult (8.3, 12.1)
 op: 'mult'  x: 8.30  y: 12.10

enter OP(x, y): sum(1.1, pickles)
  error: invalid input.

enter OP(x, y): sum(1.1, 2.2)
 op: 'sum'  x: 1.10  y: 2.20

enter OP(x, y):
```

Let me know if you have further question, or if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do, thank you very much

Comment: You are very welcome. Good luck with your coding!